# Function doesn't work on mobile but works on pc (get innerwidth)

Tags: javascript, android

I have written a function to enable a button when the screen is less than 768 width. It works on PC but it doesn't work on mobile, which is the whole point. I really don't know how to fix this?

I've tried multiple codes but only this one works on PC when I adjust the screen to a smaller size, the rest didn't work at all.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    document.getElementById("form-submit").disabled = false; 
  }
};
```

I want to make this  simple code work on mobile.

Comment: Have you checked it on actual mobile browser? Because you are using `window.onload` function, that might not trigger when you resize.

Comment: This link might help you out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onresize_window

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments! I've checked it when i resize the browser and than refresh and that works. I've also checked it on my mobile phone on samsung internet and google chrome for mobile. But in both cases it still will not work. I only want to unlock a button when you are on your mobile device.